# Group of translations modulo $1$

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading the book ["The Banach-Tarski Paradox" by Stan Wagon](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BbtI8afkFVTMnGJXL1Z_bhWZQXXJjoui). The Theorem 1.5 (page no:7) it states the following:

> **Theorem 1.5 (AC).**  $S^1$ is countably $SO_2$-paradoxical. If $G$ denotes the group of translations modulo $1$ acting on $[0,1)$, then $[0,1)$ is countably $G$-paradoxical.

But I can't understand what is meant here by **"$G$ denotes the group of translations modulo $1$"*.* What group is this?

Please give its definition. Thank you.

Comment: Consider the folliwing operation on $I = [0, 1)$. If $x , y \in I$, then $x \oplus y = x + y$ when $x + y \in I$, otherwise $x \oplus y = x + y - 1$. Then the group of translations modulo $1$ is given by the transformations on $I$ of the form $t(y) : x \mapsto x \oplus y$, for $y \in I$.

Comment: This group is isomorphic to $S^{1}$ (regarded as a subgroup of the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers) under the isomorphism sending $t(y)$ to $e^{i 2 \pi y}$.

Comment: @ A Caranti...Oh..thanks a lot. The group of translation mod 1, $G=\{t_y|y \in [0,1)\}$ is isomorphic to $S^1$ as you mentioned.